# how to add gesture recognizer to ccsprite in cocos2d iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am beginner in Cocos2D. I want to add gesture on particular CCSprite, but I got gesture on CCLayer. My requirement is to add gesture on CCSprite. How to do this?

My code:

```
-(id) initWithMask
{

    CCSprite *mask=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"circle_mask.png"];
    [self addChild:moveGlopFront z:1];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]                     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePushSceneGestureRecognizer:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRecognizer];

    swipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

    swipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
}

-(void)handlePushSceneGestureRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)aGestureRecognizer
{

    for(CCNode *child in layer.children)
    {
        [child stopAllActions];
    }

    for(CCNode *child in layer.children)
    {
    [moveGlopFront setTexture:[moveGlopBack texture]];
    [moveGlopFront runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCRotateBy   actionWithDuration:5.0 angle:360]]];
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't add gesture recognizers to sprites, you always add them to the cocos2d view (CCDirector's view/openGLView property).

Answer (score 0):

Add your gesture recognizers to the layers instead, and use CGRectIntersectsRect selector to check if you touch the sprite, in your gesture recognizers implementation.